# Binomial Coefficients Identity (unsure if this is true)

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Does anyone know if the following result is true?

$$ \sum_{x = 0} \binom{n - x(k-1)}{k} = \sum_{x = 0} \binom{n-1 - x(k-1)}{k} + \sum_{x = 0} \binom{n-k - x(k-1)}{k}$$

where $k \leq n$ and $n, k$ are positive?

Edit: Sorry, I probably should give more background. I was working on the following [problem](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/474/D) and from this problem I thought about the above identity.

Comment: What have you tried? EG Have you tested with some small cases?

Comment: Hey, I updated the problem to give some background information. I will write a program to test some values a bit later.

Answer (score 0):

For example, take $k=2,n=3$, then
 $$\text{LHS = }\sum_{x=0}\binom{3-x(1)}{2}=\binom{3}{2}+\binom{2}{2}=3+1=4$$
$$\text{RHS = }\sum_{x=0} \binom{2-x(1)}{2}+\sum_{x=0} \binom{1-x(1)}{2}=\binom{2}{2}+\sum_{x=0} \binom{1-x(1)}{2}$$ The second term does not exist, thus we can conclude that the identity is not true for all $n,k$.